# Interface Hell or Acceptable Design?

Tags: design-patterns, interface, strategy-pattern

I am refactoring some legacy code that was doing close to the same thing over and over via a case statement:

```
switch(identifier)
    case firstIdentifier: 
        (SomeCast).SetProperties(Prop1,Prop2,Prop3);
        break;
    ...
    case anotherIdentifier:
        (SomeDifferentCast).SetProperties(Prop1, Prop2, Prop3);
        break;
```

So, I tried to create a unique interface so that this could become

```
(SameInterfaceCast).SetProperties(Prop1,Prop2,Prop3);
```

However, I then found that some items do not even use all of the properties. So, I began to think of something more like this:

```
if(item is InterfaceForProp1)
    (InterfaceForProp1).SetProp1(Prop1);
if(item is InterfaceForProp2)
    (InterfaceForProp2).SetProp2(Prop2);
if(item is InterfaceForProp3)
    (InterfaceForProp3).SetProp3(Prop3);
```

and you could create a class like this:

```
public class MyClassUsesProp2And3 : InterfaceForProp2, InterfaceForProp3
```

However, I am afraid that I am overly fragmenting this code and it could balloon too much. Maybe I should not be too fearful of what will essentially be one method interfaces, but I wanted to see if I am missing a design pattern before going down this path? (the only ones that popped into my mind but were not quite the right fit were the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) patterns)

**UPDATE**

All properties are unique types.

Ultimately, this is a form of dependency injection. The code is too messed up to use something like Ninject right now, but eventually I might even be able to get rid of some of these and use an injection container. There is also currently some logic that is being done beyond just setting a variable. This is all legacy code, and I am just trying to clean it up little by little.

Comment: Are Prop1, Prop2, and Prop3 of the same type?  Because I'm almost thinking you want a superclass for InterfaceForProp1, InterfaceForProp2, and InterfaceForProp3 that has a SetProp() method that takes an argument of whatever type Prop1, Prop2, and Prop3 are.

Comment: Perhaps Prop1, Prop2, and Prop3 are properties of a domain concept that isn't yet represented by an object. That might simplify your interface.

Comment: @dmn I just updated my question adding that all the types are different. If they were all the same then this would be cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to make the actors (type with setProp methods) the same type 'Actor' AND make the properties (prop1...n) the same type 'Prop'. This would reduce your code to

```
actor.setProp(prop)
```

If you want to avoid using instanceOf, the only way I can think of is to go with the Visitor pattern, making 'Prop' the visitor. I would also use template method to make my life easier. In Java I would make it look like this (for two actual kinds of Prop).

```
class Actor {

    protected void set(Prop1 p1) {
        // Template method, do nothing
    }

    protected void set(Prop2 p2) {
        // Template method, do nothing
    }

    public void setProp(Prop p) {
        p.visit(this);
    }

    public interface Prop {
        void visit(Actor a);
    }

    public static Prop makeComposite(final Prop...props ) {
        return new Prop() {

            @Override
            public void visit(final Actor a) {
                for (final Prop p : props) {
                    p.visit(a);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static class Prop1 implements Prop {
        public void visit(Actor a) {
            a.set(this);
        }
    }

    public static class Prop2 implements Prop {
        public void visit(Actor a) {
            a.set(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to do stuff like this:

```
    ConcreteActor a = new ConcreteActor();
    Prop p = Actor.makeComposite(new ConcreteProp1(42), new ConcreteProp2(-5));
    a.setProp(p);
```

...which is super nice!

Comment: If I read this correctly, I would need to make as many calls as I have properties, but it avoids the extra if's:    `actor.setProp(Prop1); actor.setProp(Prop2);` etc? I knew of the visitor pattern, but never used it and I was very vague on the implementation until now. If I am correct about the usage, I do really like this...however I dont have control over the property classes currently. I will do a more major refactoring so that I can do this at a later time, though. Giving you the check since you explained this the best and it is what I feel is the right answer (Even if I cant't use it)

Comment: Thank you for the check! This is not the conventional use of Visitor, but it solves the problem at hand. Well yes, you have to add a new set() for each new property, but if you add a new property all you need is to add it as a new dummy template method on the base class Actor, and then a specific implementation for the subclasses of Actor that need to be able to responde to the new property. This is pretty much the minimal change scenario.

Comment: I cleaned up the code and made it a bit more concrete + added a method for making a Composite from the props. Even if you have no control over the actual properties classes, you can always wrap them in this structure when you refactor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a "right" answer to this but here's what I would do.

```
class Properties {
    prop1
    prop2
    prop3
}

interface PropertySetable {
     setProperties(Properties prop);
}
public class MyClassUsesProp2And3 implements PropertySetable {
    setProperties(Properties prop) {
       //I know I need only 2 and 3
       myProp2 = prop.prop2;
       myProp3 = prop.prop3;
    }

}
```

In calling function, you should not have a cast.

```
 someFunc(..., PropertySetable, Properties,...) {
      PropertySetable.setProperties(Properties); 
 }
```

That is the basic structure.

You should encapsulate Properties - make properties private and have relevant constructors. Or use the Builder pattern to build Properties... and many more..

Comment: See, but you are still essentially doing the same thing here. I would really like to avoid passing around variables that arent even used.

Comment: Not really... I prefer to let the classes decide what they need.. and not the calling code. What is your objection to passing the `Properties` object? It seems wasteful to me to ask the class what they need and then give it to them. Just take the whole thing - and take what you need. Its better than passing individual properties - because of maintainability. If you are passing pointers/references, then performance/memory wise, its not a problem either.

Comment: +1 because the more I thought about it, this method fits. The visitor pattern is better, though. Which is why I gave it the checkmark

Comment: Visitor pattern is better. However, it involves more work and you may need to refactor you legacy classes more. But if you can take it, the Visitor is defiantly the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on why you want to refactor the code in the first place.

- If you want to get rid of the switch block entirely then you'll have to implement an interface with one method taking three arguments.  Each class would have to figure out which arguments apply and what to do with those arguments.
- If you want to reduce the overall amount of code then I'm not sure that adding the class-specific property setting logic is any less code than the original switch statement
- If you want to exploit your editor's code completion capability to insert the correct method with the correct number of properties/args then just implement the correct method(s) on each class and avoid the interface altogether

Comment: IMO, your third option is not a reason at all. My main reason for changing the code was to make the code more maintainable and readable, making it more SOLID. The visitor pattern is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is the standard solution when you are faced with switch statements and typecasts. Your code for each case will go into a separate method in the visitor class. And your classes will each implement only one interface -- an `accept` method to accept visitors. You will end up with more code than you have now but it will read a lot cleaner.